# How to retrieve object Column from DataSource RowFilter

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, datasource, rowfilter

I'm currently trying to retrieve a column from a DataTable that contains columns with object inside some certains columns.

Let see :

```
(this.CohortGrid.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter =  string.Format("CohortFormation.Name LIKE '*{0}*'", ddlFormation.SelectedItem.Text);
```

I got these columns inside my DataTable :

[0] : Id

[1] : Name

[2] : Status

[3] : CohortFormation

[4] : RoomCol

[5] : InstructorCol

[6] : EmployeeCol

The column CohortFormation is an object that contains a Id and a Name.

So, I'm trying to retrieve the Name of CohortFormation like this `CohortFormation.Name LIKE`
but it return me :

> Unable to find column

In the Grid View TemplateField I can do `<%# Eval("CohortFormation.Name") %>` and it works pretty well. But in the code behind how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found a solution and it's working pretty well !

I loop through the DataTable and remove the rows that is not equals to the value that is selected in the DropDownList -> ddlFormation.

There is the code :

```
  CohortCollection cohortCol = (CohortCollection)Session["cohortCol"];

        foreach(Cohort cohort in cohortCol.ToList())
        {
            if(cohort.Status.Id != int.Parse(ddlFormation.SelectedItem.Value))
            {
                cohortCol.Remove(cohort);
            }
        }

        this.CohortGrid.DataSource = cohortCol;
        this.CohortGrid.DataBind();
```

So, the trick is to loop on the list and not the DataTable and if it's not equals we remove the object. Finally, we bind the data.

It works perfectly !